# How to remove lines between cells in Material UI Table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I tried editing all sorts of CSS and elements of [`Table`](https://mui.com/components/tables/#tables) and `TableCells` but still I can't make the lines go away. How do you make lines go away between rows in the `Table` element in Material UI?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.  We can't guess what the issue is..Help us to help you.

Comment: try `.MuiTableCell-root{border-bottom: none}`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As mentioned by Soothran in the comments, this is controlled by the bottom border of `TableCell`. Below is one way to customize this.

```
import MuiTableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";

const TableCell = withStyles({
  root: {
    borderBottom: "none"
  }
})(MuiTableCell);
```

[image: Edit Table no lines]

Answer (score 42):

If you're using **MUI v5**, you can use the `sx` props. The new MUI release also added `tableCellClasses` object to help you reference the component CSS className in a type-safe way instead of using the hardcoded string `"MuiTableCell-root"`:

```
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from "@mui/material/TableCell";
```

```
<Table
  sx={{
    [`& .${tableCellClasses.root}`]: {
      borderBottom: "none"
    }
  }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 57325232/how-to-remove-lines-between-cells-in-table-in-material-ui]

Comment: where can u find more info on tableCellClasses?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial every MUI component has a `[component]Classes` const. It's briefly mentioned [here](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#replace-nested-classes-selectors-with-global-class-names).

Comment: This piece of info worth more points than the answer itself  

Comment: `import { TableCell, tableCellClasses } from '@mui/material'` worked for me :) - makes for a nicer looking import line

Answer (score 12):

To remove the border lines of the particular Table Cell use  :

```
<TableCell sx={{ borderBottom: "none" }}>
  {/* ... */}
</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 9):

To remove the border from a specific TableRow you can use:

```
sx={{ "& td": { border: 0 } }}
```

Comment: this works but heads up: it'll also apply to your expandable inner tables if you have them

Answer (score 2):

classes={{ root: classes.MuiTableCell}}   class of a Tablecell,then 
MuiTableCell: {
borderBottom: "none"
}

This works me fine to remove the BorderBottom line of a tablecell.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the table border lines:

`.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell {border-bottom: none !important;}`