# Align items into table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-typescript

I want to implement a basic table with listing items as key-value:

```
import React, {FormEvent} from 'react';
import {Box, Button, Container, Grid, TextField, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';

export default function Hello( ) {
 
  return (
      <Container>
                      <Grid container
                            direction="column"
                            justifyContent="space-between"
                            alignItems="flex-start">

                          <Grid item>
                              <Box pl={2} pb={3}>
                                  <Typography variant="h4">
                                      Summary
                                  </Typography>
                              </Box>
                          </Grid>
                      </Grid>

                     

                      <Grid item>
                          <Grid
                              container
                              direction="row"
                              justifyContent="flex-start"
                              alignItems="flex-start"
                          >
                              <Grid item>
                                  <Box component="div"
                                       sx={{display: 'inline', p: 2, m: 2}}
                                  >
                                      Country 123
                                  </Box>

                              </Grid>
                              <Grid item>
                                  <Box component="div"
                                       sx={{display: 'inline', p: 2, m: 2}}
                                  >
                                      USA
                                  </Box>
                              </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                      </Grid>
 

                      <Grid item>
                          <Grid
                              container
                              direction="row"
                              justifyContent="flex-start"
                              alignItems="flex-start"
                          >
                              <Grid item>
                                  <Box component="div"
                                       sx={{display: 'inline', p: 2, m: 2}}
                                  >
                                      Country 4323
                                  </Box>

                              </Grid>
                              <Grid item>
                                  <Box component="div"
                                       sx={{display: 'inline', p: 2, m: 2}}
                                  >
                                      USA
                                  </Box>
                              </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                      </Grid>

                     

                      <Grid item>
                          <Grid
                              container
                              direction="row"
                              justifyContent="flex-start"
                              alignItems="flex-start"
                          >
                              <Grid item>
                                  <Box component="div"
                                       sx={{display: 'inline', p: 2, m: 2}}
                                  >
                                      Country
                                  </Box>

                              </Grid>
                              <Grid item>
                                  <Box component="div"
                                       sx={{display: 'inline', p: 2, m: 2}}
                                  >
                                      USA
                                  </Box>
                              </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                      </Grid>
 
         
      </Container>
  )
}
```

Sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-srtlsp?file=Hello.tsx

I have values in different size which push the other values. Is it possible to have Strings in different size without pushing the other values?

Is there some better way to implement this functionality?

Comment: Why don't you use [`Table`](https://mui.com/components/tables/#main-content) component?

Comment: I can use it but I need to remove all css from the table. Cna you give me some example please how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by removing all css? do you want to remove all borders or anything else?

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the borders.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57325232/9449426) question.

Comment: There is a still table border into the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-s0r9u?fontsize=14 Any idea how to remove it?

Comment: That's the box shadow of the `Paper` component. Just remove it if you don't want

Comment: Can you show me code example, please?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-no-lines-forked-9nvv5

Comment: How I can remove the head?

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly I suggest you use tables instead of grids for this. But if you want to make this work, give a fixed width to your boxes like this:

```
     <Box
              component="div"
              sx={{ display: 'inline-', p: 2, m: 2, width: 100 }}
            >
              Country 4323
    </Box>
```

Now they will be inline , since there is a width set. Notice that the width should always be more than the content of what you are putting in the box.

Comment: Can you show me how to make Materia-UI table transparent?

Comment: @PeterPenzov is MU a must for you? Plain Html & CSS is far easier in this case.

Comment: Yes I want to use Material UI in this project.