# Changing the color of a hovered TableHead Column Identifier in MaterialUI

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to style child `th` elements using the `TableHead` [MaterialUI component](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-head/). I've been able to change many of the properties, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the hover color.

Here's the css I've implemented so far ([with sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-table-head-color-changes-t4w9it?file=/demo.tsx:4279-4549)):

```
<TableHead
  sx={{
    "& th": {
      color: "blue",
      backgroundColor: "yellow"
    },
    "& .MuiTableSortLabel-root.Mui-active, .MuiTableSortLabel-root.Mui-active .MuiTableSortLabel-icon": {
      color: "red"
    }
  }}
>
```

Also... bonus points if you can change the `css` selector code to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69230921/12728698)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add this style to `sx` prop of your `TableHead` component:

```
// for default hover color
"& .MuiTableSortLabel-root:hover, .MuiTableSortLabel-root:hover .MuiTableSortLabel-icon": {
  color: "brown"
},
// for active case hover color
"& .MuiTableSortLabel-root.Mui-active:hover, .MuiTableSortLabel-root.Mui-active:hover .MuiTableSortLabel-icon": {
  color: "pink"
}
```

Here is the [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-table-head-color-changes-forked-sjuxgl?file=/demo.tsx:4544-4691) of this solution.

Comment: thanks! Also, I figured out how to use the `classes` variables from MUI, the first one would look like this: `[\`& .${tableSortLabelClasses.root}.Mui-active, ${tableSortLabelClasses.root}.Mui-active ${tableSortLabelClasses.icon}\`]`

Comment: forgot two dots.... and now I can't edit... here's the correct one `\`& .${tableSortLabelClasses.root}.Mui-active, .${tableSortLabelClasses.root}.Mui-active .${tableSortLabelClasses.icon}\``